# QGIS v.transform output extent not lining up with input

Tags: qgis, vector, extents, affine-transformation

I am using the updated Affine tool (v.transform) to rescale my vector layer (containing multiple polygons). I want to shrink each polygon to half of its size. So I enter in 0.5 for both the x and y scale. I leave everything else as default and then hit run. The output is in another extent and is located somewhere weird. I tried setting the extent argument to my original vector, but I still get the same output problem. I've also tried SAGA's transform tool. Same problem.

**v.trasnform tool inputs:**

[image]

**original vector files extent:**

[image]

**transformed vector files extent:**

[image]

It's also weird that the feature count increased. I went through the file and noticed that overlapping sections were being split into their own polygon. Not sure why that is happening.

Comment: If you devide the x and y coordinates by 2, isn't the result what can be expected?

Comment: I understand what you are getting at and that makes sense, but then how would I shrink/rescale my polygons to half their size? And, what is going on with the extra features?

Comment: I figured out a way to do it without running into the issue I was having. I installed the Shape Tools Plugin and used the Geodesic Transformation tool to scale about the centroid.

Comment: Buffering with negative value is one way but it does not maintain the shape of the geometries.  With affine transformation you must scale and then move the new geometries around the original place. It feels like https://postgis.net/docs/ST_TransScale.html is made for simplifying the procedure. Sorry, I haven't done that myself yet.

Comment: No worries, thank you for the advice and help.